# Print image data ESC POS

Tags: printing

I'm trying print image date using ESC POS commands, but until now just crap is printing out.

Just for record, I'm using a Diebold TSP 143MU ESC/POS mode.

Command ESC *

I'm using Java, printing direct to USB port, every thing is fine, bar code, black text, underline etc., just the image data is not working... I got in the Internet some examples but still printing just codes and sometimes bytes, nothing of image: (

Thank in advance.

Comment: Hello guys, I found the solution here in this link http://goo.gl/MJCjxJ check it out!!

it's working perfectly now!!

Enjoy!!